# how to add a topics to the website without editing the code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, asp.net-mvc

Hi guys i have a web site, there is a content I want let admin editing it "TEXT and pictures" without having to edit the code in order to add some topics,how i can do that i'm using ASP.net with c# is there to add a box like the box of inserting topic in stackoverflow

Comment: Please read the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section in order to get better answers to your questions.

Comment: Buy the box at your local store, preferably a cardboard or plastic box, and send it to Google with a note of how you want the box inserted into the website, they will fix this for you, no problem!

Comment: @adeneo really not funny

Answer (score 0):

What you're saying is what a CMS (Content Management System) is for, and it seems that your website is just a simple website.

There's plenty of CMS options out there, since [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) (PHP) to the [Umbraco](https://umbraco.com/) (.NET) - plenty more on Google - and you need to shape your website into one of them, or, if you want to have the work... you need to develop your own system... add those textboxes and image selectors, save the choices to a database, and show the text and images from those saved choices...

best option is actually set up an empty CMS and replicate what you currently have, it's easier and you will get all from the start.